# Show $e^x \leq x+e^{x^2}$ for $x\geq1 $ and $x \leq -1$.

Tags: inequality

Show $e^x \leq x+e^{x^2}$ for $x\geq1 $ and $x \leq -1$.

So $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...$ so it suffices to show that $1+\frac{x^2}{2!}... \leq e^{x^2}=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}+\frac{x^6}{3!}+...$.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponential is strictly increasing. Hence for $x\ge 1$, we use $x^2\ge x$ to conclude $$ e^{x^2}+x>e^{x^2}\ge e^x.$$
An important well-known inequality for the exponential is
$$ e^t\ge 1+t\qquad\text{for all }t\in\Bbb R.$$
In fact, here we need it only for $t\ge0$, in which case it can also be seen from the power series (we drop only positive terms).
Therefore, for $x\le -1$
$$ e^{x^2}+x\ge x^2+x+1=1+(-x)((-x)+1)\ge 1=e^0>e^x.$$

Comment: It is not true that $$x^2+x+1=1+(-x)((-x)+1)$$ the right side is $1-x+x^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = e^{x^2} + x - e^x$.

For $x \ge 1$ it is pretty simple since $e^{x^2} - e^x > 0$, so $f(x) > 0 $

For $x \le -1$ we'll swap $x$ with $t=-x$ to get function $g(t) = e^{t^2} - t - e^{-t}$. And we want to show that $g$ is $\ge 0 $ for $t \ge 1$.

We have $e^{t} \ge 1+t$, so $-e^{-t} \ge -\frac{1}{1+t} > -1$

Moreover $e^{t^2} \ge 1+t^2$, and by that we get:

$g(t) \ge 1+t^2 - t - 1 = t(t-1) \ge 0$ for $t \ge 1$

So $f$ is $\ge 0$ for $x \in (-\infty,-1] \cup [1,+\infty)$ and that is exactly what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$x+e^{x^2}\ge x+e^{|x|} \ge x+1+|x|+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...\ge |x|+1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...\ge e^x$